# How to set UICollectionView inside UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I am trying to add `UICollectionViewControllers` inside `UIView` class.

I cant add the controls.

```
CGRect viewframes=CGRectMake(0,400,self.view.bounds.size.width, 
self.view.bounds.size.height/2);

self.button=[[view2 alloc]initWithFrame:viewframes];   
self.button.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor]; 
[self.view addSubview:self.button];
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you have so far.....

Comment: {                                                               CGRect viewframes=CGRectMake(0,400,self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height/2);                                         }                                                               (Note :self.button is my uiview variable,view2 is my uicollectionviewcell class)
      {                                                         self.button=[[view2 alloc]initWithFrame:viewframes];
                 self.button.backgroundColor=[UIColor grayColor];  
        [self.view addSubview:self.button];                         }

Comment: please update your answer and style your code with the { Button

Comment: I treid to edit the post there.

Comment: Thank you for the edit ,Is There any sources available for Uicollectionview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add UICollectionView control to your xib and set outlet of that and also add it's delegate methods UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate to .h file .

Add below code to your .m file

```
 #pragma mark Collection View Methods
 - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
     return UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 10, 10, 10);
 }

 - (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
     return [urlArray count];
 }

 - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
     return CGSizeMake(140, 140);
 }

 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
 {
  GalleryCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     cell.tag=indexPath.row;
     return cell;
 }
```

If you are using custom cell and you want to reload Collection view than add below code

```
[YourCollectionview registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"GalleryCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
[YourCollectionview reloadData];
```

Comment: I don't have 15 reputation to Vote

Comment: Thank you  how to increase reputations

Comment: ok now your reputation increased .. now vote up my answer... and for increase reputation give answer of other people's questions

Comment: Noted i Will do the same

Comment: When i call reload data its reloading the whole view any sugession what to do?